# ASP.NET - Ternary Operator not working properly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I would want to have a changing Enrollment Status depending on the existence of a record. However, my current syntax is not functioning properly. I have a record that is supposed to show "Unenrolled" as a status but it does not. It only goes to the "Not Enrolled" status.

**Additional info:** I tried reshuffling the ternary operators and it only works on whatever is the first and ignores the conditions in between. Like in my code below it will only apply "Enrolled" status correctly and the rest will only be "Not Enrolled" completely ignoring the other 2 conditions.

Here is the method:

```
    // GET: Enrollment
    public ActionResult Enrollment()
    {
        //Query for Children
        var children = from x in db.child_t
                       select new ViewModels.ChildViewModel
                       {
                           child_id = x.child_id,
                           last_name = x.last_name,
                           first_name = x.first_name,
                           middle_name = x.middle_name,
                           ext_name = x.ext_name,
                           sex = x.sex,
                           birthdate = x.birthdate,
                           sibling_status = ((from s in db.sibling_t where (s.child_id == x.child_id) select s).Count() > 0),
                           child_survey_status = ((from cs in db.child_survey_t where (cs.child_id == x.child_id) select cs).Count() > 0),
                           parent_status = ((from tp in db.tn_child_parent_t where (tp.child_id == x.child_id) select tp).Count() > 0),
                           home_status = ((from h in db.home_t where (h.child_id == x.child_id) select h).Count() > 0),
                           enrollment_status =
                            (

                              (from h in db.tn_enrollment_t
                                where (h.child_id == x.child_id && h.enrollment_date != null && h.unenrollment_date == null && h.completed_date == null)
                                orderby h.enrollment_date descending
                                select h).FirstOrDefault() != null ? "Enrolled" :

                              (from h in db.tn_enrollment_t
                               where (h.child_id == x.child_id && h.enrollment_date != null && h.unenrollment_date != null && h.completed_date == null)
                               orderby h.enrollment_date descending
                               select h).FirstOrDefault() != null ? "Unenrolled" :

                              (from h in db.tn_enrollment_t
                               where (h.child_id == x.child_id && h.enrollment_date != null && h.unenrollment_date == null && h.completed_date != null)
                               orderby h.enrollment_date descending
                               select h).FirstOrDefault() != null ? "Completed" : 

                               "Not Enrolled"
                            ),
                           program_id =
                            ((from p in db.tn_enrollment_t
                                where (p.child_id == x.child_id)
                                orderby p.enrollment_date descending
                                select p.program_id).FirstOrDefault())
                       };

        return View(children.ToList());


    }
```

The first record in the image below should be the one with "Unenrolled" status already.
[image]

To make things clear here's the condition for my Enrollment Status:

[image]

Comment: hi why not to use case in linq it will be single query and more readable ?

Comment: can you specify the field values of `tn_enrollment_t` for that record you think it must be as "Unenrolled"?

Comment: @YashveerSingh Will try to work on that! So far this is the first way I thought of to implement such conditions.

Comment: @S.Serp Placed it already as edits!